# What does 콧대는 하늘을 찔러 mean?

Tags: translation

I want to know the meaning of the sentence "콧대는 하늘을 찔러."

I heard it, and I did some research. I read that it can mean, "My confidence reaches the sky," but I want to make sure this is true!

Comment: welcome to stackexchange! please be sure to mark the best answer to your questions correct to help others.

Comment: Feeling of `콧대` in this sentence is more like *arrogance* rather than *confidence*.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty much a not very nice way of saying "stuck up" or "full of yourself".

The compound word 콧대 is the profile/ridge (대) of the nose (코).  The "ㅅ" 받침 acts as the glue in the compound word just as in the "shore" or waters (바다) edge (가) "waters-edge" (바닷가).

하늘 is as you expect: the sky, and 찌르다 is the verb "to poke" conjugated into 찔러 which is, of course, 반말 without any honorific feeling to it.

Comment: Small correction: 찔리다 is "to be poked".  The verb "to poke" is 찌르다, which is inflected to 찔러 here (it's a 르불규칙 verb).  찔리다 would inflect and become 찔려.

Comment: @jick you are so right. thank you! i've corrected the spelling in my post.